# Batch file with "menu" for deleting files referencing path from a text file

Tags: batch-file

Good Day to All,

Please pardon me if my question may appear odd. I was not able to pinpoint past examples that suit the ideal script that i wish to accomplish.

Currently, i have the following script. Essentially is to delete files from folders whose location is listed in a text file (del_location.txt).

`For /F "tokens=*" %%A in (del_location.txt) do del \Q "%%A"`

I did not choose to use `Forfiles`, as the network i am working on in my company is at Windows 2000 without the ability to run `Forfiles` and due to security reasons, are not able to install any patches.

There are multiple location in del_location.txt and there are instances that my users may not wish to delete all the listed location. Hence i am wondering how do i write a "menu" function, that reads off the listed location in del_location.txt and `ECHO` it as a selection. Lets the user choose the selection in a Yes/No fashion before the commencement of the delete sequence? Thus allowing the user to "walk off" from the terminal after choosing what he wants to delete.

*Also, from as far as i can find online, without `Forfiles`, i would not be able to choose to delete only files that are older than N days. Am i right to state so?

Your help and advices are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can `set` each lines in *del_location.txt* to an array. Since batch don't support array, then we need to do it manually.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:main
set lines=0

For /F "tokens=*" %%A in (del_location.txt) do (
    set array[!lines!]=%%A
    set /a lines+=1
    echo !lines!^) %%A
)

echo. & echo.
set /p choice=Which file do you want to delete? ^>

if %choice% lss 1 goto main
if %choice% gtr %lines% goto main

set /a choice-=1

del /Q !array[%choice%]!
echo. & echo.
echo "!array[%choice%]!" was deleted successfully ^^!
echo. & echo.
choice /c:yn /m "Do you want to delete more files? [y/n]" /n
if %errorlevel% == 1 goto main
if %errorlevel% == 2 exit /b
```

This script only provided for delete 1 file per turn. So if you want to batch delete, try to modify it yourself, ask anyone or me if you stuck at a point.
I think there's a way to delete files based on date other than `forfiles` method. Btw, `dir SOURCE /o:d` list and sort out files based on date.

Comment: Hi Dark Fang, i tried to run the script but it seem to have some errors somewhere that i cannot locate. i'm making a guess on this particularly odd ---- !lines!^)----- on line 8, that has an close bracket without a prior opening one. Pardon my brevity as i am not well versed in computing language. But i do see how you are putting the lines in del_location.txt in an array.

Comment: The purpose I put `^)` is to `echo` ")" without CMD knowing it is a closing parenthesis for the script. I tested it and it seems to work fine. Do you list folder name instead of file name in *del_location.txt*? My script won't delete folders because of 'del' command.